# Convert TimeStamp To Joda DateTime Without Any Timezone Conversion

Tags: spring, datetime, jodatime, spring-jdbc

I have timestamp value in Oracle database column stored in UTC. I want to read it through spring's jdbcTemplate and convert it to joda DateTime object without any timezone conversion i.e. read it as is without converting or losing timezone. 
For e.g. if the input timestamp is `2019-03-08 15:07:37.232`, I would like to have the DateTime object with the value `2019-03-08T15:07:37.232Z` 
How can I achieve this?

Note this code - `new DateTime(timestamp.getTime(), DateTimeZone.UTC))` does not help since it assumes that the input timestamp is in local timezone and reconverts it to UTC. For the above input is `2019-03-08 15:07:37.232` the outcome comes to `2019-03-08T09:37:37.232Z`

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I have understood, if you know that the database timestamp is in UTC, but Oracle doesn’t know (it’s not a `timestamp with time zone`), your time stamp of `2019-03-08 15:07:37.232` will be retrieved incorrectly as this date and time in your time zone, so you need to convert it back to UTC. Oracle and Spring’s jdbcTemplate are not my home field, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution that worked was to change the way the timestamp column value is retrieved from the database. The below snippet works for converting a timestamp column value to joda DateTime without losing/converting the timezone

```
new DateTime(resultSet.getTimestamp("CreatedDateTime",
                        Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))), DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

Hope that helps others too.

Answer (score -1):

If you already have a DateTime object there is method

```
public DateTime withZone(DateTimeZone newZone)
```

which would return a copy of datetime with a different time zone, preserving the millisecond instant

eg:- `dateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)`

Comment: I don't have a DateTime object. I have a Timestamp object from database.